# How to change the location of a file which is being saved in .camel subdirectory by default

Tags: java, spring, file, apache-camel

I'm passing the following path to myBean through dependency injection and want the file to be saved in 
C:\user\folder1\export\out\

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.company.myClass">
    <property name="myDirectory"
        value="${user.home}${file.separator}folder1${file.separator}export${file.separator}out${file.separator}" />
    <property name="myDao" ref="myDao" />
</bean>
```

but instead my process is saving the file in the .camel directory. 
C:\user\folder1\export\out\.camel

I cannot afford the file to stay in .camel location so I will have to eliminate the camel default behavior. Anyone has any idea how to do this?

Following is the java code for reference where I create a fileoutputstream for creating the file.

```
final FileOutputStream fos =
        new FileOutputStream(myDirectory + "ABCD_"
            + dateFormatFile.format(new Date()) + "_EXPORT.xlsm");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the move option(default = .camel) in your camel file uri. See http://camel.apache.org/file2.html.

Comment: Hi, I saw this link before posting the question but couldn't get how would I change this default behavior. Can you please elaborate it a little in my scenario.

Thanks

Comment: How does your camel route looks like?